# count number of common rows in multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, loops

Assume we have multiple data frames say df1,df2,df3,...  What is the most efficient R way to count the number of rows that are identical across multiple data frames. Nested multiple loops is not the answer, right?

Thanks

Comment: Next time please post a reproducible example. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find how many times duplicated rows repeat in R data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201074/find-how-many-times-duplicated-rows-repeat-in-r-data-frame)

Comment: sorry, I thought the statement is clear enough and no example needed. I will add example whenever possible. Thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hacky, but should work:

```
df1$comp <- paste(df1$V1,df1$V2,df1$V3,..., df1$Vn, sep="")
df2$comp <- paste(df2$V1,df2$V2,df2$V3,..., df2$Vn, sep="")
```

etc

Then

```
# Number of complete rows in df1 that are in df2.
summary(df1$comp %in% df2$comp)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1=data.frame(A=11:13,B=111:113)   
df2=data.frame(A=22:24,B=222:224)   
df3=data.frame(A=c(33:35,11),B=c(333:335,111))
```

if you are happy to bind the data.frame manually:

```
> df = rbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

(otherwise you can also use):

```
> df = do.call(what=rbind,args=mget(paste("df",1:3,sep=""))))
```

Then

```
> library(plyr)  
> ddply(.data=df,.variables=colnames(df),.fun=nrow)
```

Where the 3rd column is the number of times each row is repeated