# How to extract information of a vector in a data frame corresponding to each unique value of another vector in the same data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Suppose I have the following data frame `data`-

```
V1   V2
A    3
A    2  
A    1
B    2
B    3
C    4
C    3
C    1
C    2
```

Now I want to extract information of each level, i.e. (`A`,`B`,`C`,`D` & `E`) of `V1`. As an example, if I choose to see the sum of different levels in `V2` for each level of `V1`, what should be the code? 
The output I want is-

```
      V1    V2
      A     6
      B     5
      C     10
```

I tried `lapply` and `sapply` but they are not giving the information I want. Of course I tried `sapply(data,unique)` which made no sense.

Also, in advance (*may be a bit trickier*), if I want to see the values in `V2` which are unique in all the levels of `V1`,how to do it?
Thanks !!

Comment: Can you show the expected output as it is not clear.  Do you need `library(data.table);setDT(data)[, if(uniqueN(V1)>1) .SD ,.(V2)]`

Comment: Do you just want `unique(data)` ? Or maybe this is helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201074/find-how-many-times-duplicated-rows-repeat-in-r-data-frame/18201245 ?

Comment: @thelatemail, actually the link you gave is not exactly what I want. I want how many values each of A,B & C has and what values are common in them.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want, in that it will find unique values which are common across different groups:

Common `V2` values in each level of `V1`

```
Reduce(intersect, split(dat$V2, dat$V1))
#[1] 3 2
```

Common `V1` values in each level of `V2`

```
Reduce(intersect, split(dat$V1, dat$V2))
#[1] "C"
```

Comment: I am sorry I am late. But it worked ! Thanks @akrun for helping as well..

Comment: Also thanks @thelatemail

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, we can find the `unique` values in 'V2' that are common across 'V1'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,uniqueN(V1)==uniqueN(data$V1) , by = V2][(V1)]$V2
#[1] 3 2
```

and the common 'V1' in each unique element of 'V2'

```
setDT(data)[, if(uniqueN(V1)==1) .SD , by = V2]$V1
#[1] "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful

```
output <- aggregate(data=df,V2~.,FUN=paste)
```

For extraction of common values in `V2` presented all the levels of `V1` use this

```
Reduce(intersect,output$V2)
```

Comment: Thanks @user2100721 , it is almost what I want. The only thing is it is giving output in list when I am trying to extract the `V2` values and using the `unlist` function is producing one single vector.

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine. For the 2nd part, I want to extract the unique values which are present in all levels. In this case A:3,2,1,B:2,3,C:4,3,1,2. So the unique values will be 2 & 3. How to get them?

Comment: Okay, let me illustrate with the example I provided. Form the first part of my query, I want to show A takes values 3,2,1. B takes values 2,3 and C takes values 4,3,1,2.
For the 2nd part, we can see that the values 2 & 3 are unique in A,B & C. I want the output as 2 & 3.