# Finding duplicates in a dataframe and returning count of each duplicate record

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like

```
col1 col2 col3
A    B    C
A    B    C
A    B    B
A    B    B
A    B    C
B    C    A
```

I want to get an output in the below format:

```
col1 col2 col3 Count
A    B    C    3 Duplicates
A    B    B    2 Duplicates
```

I dont want to use any specific column in the function to find the duplicates.

That is the reason of not using add_count from dplyr.

Using duplicate will have

```
    col1 col2 col3 count
2   A    B    C    3
3   A    B    B    2
5   A    B    C    3
```

So not the desired output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201074/find-how-many-times-duplicated-rows-repeat-in-r-data-frame/18201245#18201245 are probably helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `group_by_all` to group by all columns and then remove the ones which are not duplicates by selecting rows which have count > 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
  count() %>%
  filter(n > 1)

#  col1  col2  col3      n
# <fct> <fct> <fct>   <int>
#1 A     B     B         2
#2 A     B     C         3
```

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah..akrun also provided the correct answers. For me , your answer is easier to understand thus marking as answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(n =.N), names(df1)][n > 1]
#   col1 col2 col3 n
#1:    A    B    C 3
#2:    A    B    B 2
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
subset(aggregate(n ~ ., transform(df1, n = 1), FUN = sum), n > 1)
#  col1 col2 col3 n
#2    A    B    B 2
#3    A    B    C 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun, I see you replying on many R related questions.I checked and it works.